# regex returning only the first found

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search for a certain word in a string data but it only returns the first match.

```
const searchFunc = (stringData, searchedType) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${searchedType}(.*)`, "g");
  var arr = regex.exec(stringData);
  while (arr !== null) {
    prefix = arr[1].replace(/[`_:'",.]/gi, "")
    return prefix;
  }
};
```

i call the search function in another one like this :

```
searchFunc(data, "path");
```

my strinData is like this :

```
{
  path: '/aaa',
  ...
},
 {
  path: '/bbb',
  ...
  },
},  
{
  path: '/ccc',
  ...
},
```

The output i get :

```
=>  /aaa
```

The output i want

```
=>  /aaa
=>  /bbb
=>  /ccc
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're calling the function with, and the expected output?

Comment: You should probably be using `while (arr = myRegexp.exec(myString)) {` and call return after the while loop. From this, it should be obvious you have one more thing to change after doing those.

Comment: @Jerry when i do it like that, my code doesn't crash but it stays stuck up

Comment: Can you think about what that means?

Comment: @koreangirl: Can you show the code after making those changes?

Comment: No, infinite loop. When should the loop be broken?

Comment: @Ry- that's the whole code, i only call the function after it to search for the word i want

Comment: @koreangirl: The code after making the changes that made it get stuck.

Comment: @Jerry normally it should be broken after it finds the whole results

Comment: @Ry- my bad, thought `while` would continue looping even if `arr` returned `null` and I'd probably be checking if `arr` was `null` at the first line of the loop to break if needed.

Comment: @Jerry: Well, there was *some* kind of infinite loop going on, so it wasn’t bad advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to put the results in, then `push` to that array in every iteration of the `while` loop, and return the array at the end of the function:

```js
const searchFunc = (stringData, searchedType) => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`${searchedType}(.*)`, "g");
  const results = [];
  let match;
  while (match = pattern.exec(stringData)) {
    results.push(match[1].replace(/[`_:'",.]/gi, ""));
  }
  return results;
};
const data = `routes: [
{
  path: '/aaa',
  xxx: {
    ...
  },
},
 {
  path: '/bbb',
  xxx: {
    ...
  },
},
{
  path: '/ccc',
  xxx: {
    ...
  },
},
],`

const prefixValue = searchFunc(data, "path");
console.log(`prefix found => ${prefixValue}`);
```

Note that this is an X/Y problem: ideally, fix whatever's serving you that string so that it gives you proper JSON instead, so that you can parse it into an object and use object/array manipulation methods instead, for example:

```js
const searchFunc = (data, prop) => data.map(obj => obj[prop]);
const dataArr = [{
    path: '/aaa',
    xxx: {},
  },
  {
    path: '/bbb',
    xxx: {},
  },
  {
    path: '/ccc',
    xxx: {},
  },
];

const prefixValue = searchFunc(dataArr, "path");
console.log(`prefix found => ${prefixValue}`);
```